# Run Function When Cell Value Changed or edit

Tags: sourceforge-appscript

Sir I have a function in google sheets Name DCP Small And I want to Run it With When Specific Cell Range (A1:A10) Changed Value.
note: The Cell value will be Changed By Human

I Don't try it From my side so please help for solve code thanks in advance